# Linux не видно jobs с других tty

Tags: linux, ubuntu, putty

Доброго времени суток.
Наткнулся на на такую проблему:
Когда посылаю процесс с консоли в bg то процесс видно только с той консоли c которой его создали. Если же логинюсь с другой консоли то при команде jobs ничего не выдает.
Почему не видно заданий?
Как можно посмотреть jobs с других консолей?
Спасибо.

Comment: Потому что unix. Процесс либо привязан к терминалу (обычная программа), либо нет (демон). А так, *man screen*, *man tmux*. Если просто посмотреть, то *man ps*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На ваш ответ отвечает man по jobs:

> The jobs utility shall display the status of jobs that were started in the current shell environment; see Shell Execution Environment.

> Команда jobs отображает состояние заданий, которые были запущены в текущем окружении оболочки; см. Shell Execution Environment.

Соответственно узнать список запущенных под собой процессов из другого терминала можно только так:

```
ps au | grep $USER
```

Дополнительно можно отфильтровать по терминалу grep'ом по нужному терминалу. Список своих открытых терминалов можно узнать так:

```
who | grep $USER
```

Answer (score 1):

[`jobs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/jobs.html) утилита показывает *задания* ([job](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_202)) только в текущем окружении ([shell execution environment](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12)). Поэтому даже в том же терминале, но в новом экземпляре `$SHELL`, вы не увидите заданий, запущенных в другой оболочке. К примеру:

```bsh
$ jobs           # сперва нет заданий
$ sleep 100 &    # запустили фоновое задание
[1] 7929
$ jobs           # оно появилось в списке заданий
[1]  + running    sleep 100
$ sleep 50 &     # запустили ещё одно задание
[2] 8097
$ jobs           # убедились что и оно в списке заданий появилось
[1]  - running    sleep 100
[2]  + running    sleep 50
$ $SHELL         # запустили дочернюю shell в том же терминале
$ jobs           # убедились что список заданий пуст в новой оболочке
$ sleep 10 &     # запустили задание в дочерней оболочке
[1] 8509
$ jobs           # убедились что видим его
[1]  + running    sleep 10
                 # вышли из дочерней zsh (Ctrl+D)
zsh: warning: 1 jobs SIGHUPed 
[1]  + 8509 hangup     sleep 10
$ jobs           # в родительской shell по-прежнему два задания
[1]  - running    sleep 100
[2]  + running    sleep 50
```

Запущенные где бы то ни было *процессы* можно с помощью `top` утилиты (или аналогах) посмотреть.

Полезно иметь представление о сеансе пользователя (login session), управлении заданиями (job control), сигналах, активных/фоновых группах процессов/заданиях, управляющем терминале ([controlling tty](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_03)) и их взаимоотношении друг с другом.

К примеру, *задание* ([job](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_202)) это совокупность процессов, созданных запуском команды/конвейера в командной строке, принадлежащих к одной группе процессов. Пример [конвейера (pipeline)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B5%D1%80_(UNIX)):

```bsh
$ ps aux | grep [k]de | gawk '{ print $2}'
```

Пример управления заданиями: <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> в терминале посылает SIGINT сигнал всем процессам в активной группе процессов (что позволяет сразу весь конвейер убить). Ещё пример: только одна [активная] группа процессов в сеансе имеет доступ к терминалу одновременно, поэтому фоновые задания останавливаются (SIGTTIN сигнал), если им необходимо прочитать ввод от пользователя.